# Is there a way in Jetpack Compose to retreive the real String value of a String Resource for a modifier's contentDescription attribute?

Tags: android, string, resources, tostring, android-jetpack-compose

I use Jetpack compose for an android app.I want to retrieve the String value of a String that is already declared in Resources.Strings. I tried everything even context but nothings seems to work.
More specifically I want to register a String value from Resources as the contentDescription of composable's modifier so that TalkBack can read this value to the user's system language.The debugger logs an int value instead of a String even when I user `.toString()` method. Here is the code.

This is the string on `values/strings.xml` file.

```
<string name="my_string">Something</string>
```

This is some of the code for the composable:

```
....modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .focusRequester(focusRequesters[1])
        .clearAndSetSemantics { contentDescription = R.string.mystring.toString() }
)
val test= (R.string.my_string)
Log.d("Test",""+ test )
```

The debugger shows an integer value to the Android Studio's Logcat. This is output of the Logcat:

```
D/Test: 2131623845
```

The expected result should have been:

```
D/Test: Something
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use the method [**`stringResource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#stringResource(kotlin.Int)):

```
val test = stringResource(R.string.my_string)

Text("text",
  modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .clearAndSetSemantics {contentDescription = test}
)
```

Comment: Hello Gabriele, already tried this but i get this error. "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

Comment: @CorrurtedDisciple check the updated answer

Comment: You have an error in your name. I think you meant Corrupted Disciple

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, there are currently two ways to do this:

1. Have the `String` prepared beforehand, as it is done in [Gabriele Mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048752/2528840)'s example, by using the `@Composable` `stringResource` function;
2. Have a `Context` variable prepared beforehand and then use `context.getString()`:

```
@Composable
fun SomeFunction() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   
   TextField(
        label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.some_label)) },
        modifier = Modifier.semantics {
             contentDescription = context.getString(R.string.some_description)
        }
   )
}
```